# Alter Table using Prisma ORM

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, prisma

Is there a way to automate alter table in Prisma ORM in node.js, like in sequelize

> https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#model-synchronization

Answer (score 1):

You can use `npx prisma db push` command to sync your `schema.prisma` state with the database.

If the model defined in schema file doesn't exist in database then it will be created, if the model is altered then the table in database will be altered to sync with schema file.

Here's the [reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#db-push) for db push command.

Comment: Does this work without data lose?

Comment: What exact error are you getting?